# Example of jOOQ query with more than 22 columns

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm looking for examples of how I can execute a jOOQ query with more than 22 rows.

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/row-value-expressions/

tells me it's possible, but I haven't been able to find an example.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6):

As of jOOQ 3.7 (and there are currently no plans to change this), 22 is the maximum number of columns that can be fetched in a *type safe* way. Beyond 22, you can still execute queries, but jOOQ's API will no longer track the type of your records. For example:

```
// Still type safe
Result<Record22<Integer, String, ..., Integer>> result =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(INT_COLUMN1, STRING_COLUMN2, ..., INT_COLUMN22)
   .from(TABLE)
   .fetch();

// Add one more column, and "lose" type safety
Result<Record> result =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(INT_COLUMN1, STRING_COLUMN2, ..., INT_COLUMN22, STRING_COLUMN23)
   .from(TABLE)
   .fetch();
```

From an API user perspective, the API *"feels"* exactly the same way, regardless if you select 22 or less columns (type safely), or 23 or more columns (without type safety).

#### Losing type safety with UNION

The difference might become most apparent when you compare type safe `UNION` queries with non-type safe ones:

```
// Still type safe
Result<Record22<Integer, String, ..., Integer>> result =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(INT_COLUMN1, STRING_COLUMN2, ..., INT_COLUMN21)
   .from(TABLE)
   .union(
//  ^^^^^ compilation error here
    select(INT_COLUMN1, STRING_COLUMN2, ..., INT_COLUMN21, INT_COLUMN22)
   .from(TABLE))
   .fetch();

// Add one more column, and "lose" type safety
Result<Record> result =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(INT_COLUMN1, STRING_COLUMN2, ..., STRING_COLUMN23)
   .from(TABLE)
   .union(
//  ^^^^^ This compiles, even if it's wrong
    select(INT_COLUMN1, STRING_COLUMN2, ..., STRING_COLUMN23, STRING_COLUMN24)
   .from(TABLE))
   .fetch();
```

Comment: Can you explain why 22 was chosen?

Comment: @StijndeWitt: Sure: Because Scala also chose 22. Now the interesting question is: Why did *they* choose 22? :)

Comment: Ha ha touche! You never bothered to ask? I guess I'm too curious for this business.  :)

Comment: The answer is out there on the interwebs. The number is pretty random (unsurprisingly). You have to stop somewhere, with most languages. Or, as Bill Gates used to say: *"22 tuple attributes ought to be enough for everybody"*